# Test loss and Training loss don't seem to change values?

Tags: google-chrome

It's supposed to be interactive but, Nothing happens when I press the play button.

Can someone tell me what's going on?

[This is what my browser is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jEGj.gif)

Comment: Where are you expecting it to print to?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have print() function, you can create your own.

```
function print(str){
   console.log(str);
}
```